# Mathematica SpringEmbedding Parameters

Tags: graph, wolfram-mathematica, embedding

I'm trying to construct a 3D graph in Mathematica, where the actual lengths of the edges are important. Taking a look at their documentation for graph drawing (http://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/GraphDrawing/GraphDrawing.pdf) I found that the Spring Embedding Algorithm might best suit my needs. The algorithm they mention specify a parameter *R* and a set of natural lengths for each edge. However, I do not know how to actually use these in Mathematica. The code I use is

```
GraphPlot[adj_mat, Method->"SpringEmbedding"]
```

and cannot find any way to alter the natural lengths or the parameter *R*. Does anyone know how to set these values?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Look up the documentation under `GraphLayout` and you will find many examples. Here is a brief code on how to use the layout specifiers with `GraphPlot`:

```
edge = RandomInteger[#] \[UndirectedEdge] # + 1 & /@ Range[0, 15];
weight = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, 16];
gr = Graph[edge, EdgeWeight -> weight];
GraphPlot[gr, 
   Method -> {"SpringEmbedding", "EdgeWeighted" -> #}] & /@ {True, 
  False}
```

Comment: When I enter that on Mathematica, it doesn't recognize Graph as a legitimate function. Does it work for you?

Comment: @MuhammadKhan Yes, it does, I tested it before I post thinks here. What version of MMA are you using?